# Redirect User to login page

Tags: redirect, login, wp-redirect, user-registration

Well I am newbie to WP and the question may sound duplicate but even after trying for few days I can not make this work.

I have integrated a custom login and registration form in my WP site which is different form usual WP login and register forms.

I need to perform the following actions

1. Redirect user to login page if directly accessed any Page URL
2. Redirect user to home page if directly accessed login/register URL.

For redirecting user to home page if tries to access login/register URL after being already logged in, I have used below code

```
function checkUser(){

$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( empty( $user->ID ) )
        return false;

    return true;   
}


function __construct(){
    add_action('init', array($this, 'checkUser'));
}
```

Even if I use `wp_redirect(site_url());exit;`; that do not seem to work and it goes into infinite loop.

Thanks.

Comment: use `is_user_logged_in()`instead.

Comment: The problem is that is_user_logged_in is a pluggable function, and is therefore loaded after this plugin logic is called. The solution is to make sure that you don't call this too early. This can be done by wrapping this logic in a function and calling it from 'init'

Comment: use `template_redirect` hook. Although it may not solve infinite redirect issue. Need to see more codes.

Comment: @Sisir thanks for responding, but it still goes into infinite loop. Could you help with these ?

Comment: share more code.. where did you instantiate the class?

Comment: The link http://designmodo.com/wordpress-custom-registration/ explains the code and I have just added another function for redirection as mentioned in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20376/discussion-between-sisir-and-slimshadddyyy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is from my previous project. The function is hooked into the `template_redirect` action. Inside the function there are 2 conditionals. The first is the the one that will redirect logged in user *away from* the login page. And the other one is to redirect non logged in user *to* the login page.

```
// add a redirect for logged out user
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_user');

function redirect_user(){
    global $current_user;
    if (is_page('login-page-for-non-logged-in-user') && is_user_logged_in()){
        $return_url = get_bloginfo('url');
        wp_redirect($return_url);
    }
    // this part is untested
    if (!is_page('login-page-for-non-logged-in-user') && !is_user_logged_in()){
        $return_url = get_bloginfo('url');
        wp_redirect($return_url);
    }
    // end of untested part
}
```

Comment: Please don't just dump your code, [edit] and add some explanation how this code might work.

Comment: Updated the answer. Thank you for the notice Mayeenul

Comment: @ifdion, it still says This webpage has a redirect loop.